# Which font is this sans serif with a straight tail on the uppercase Q?

Tags: font-identification

[image][image]

I have tried almost every font identification by image program on the web but to no avail.

This is as far as I know a Sans Serif Font. The only font I have found similar to this is Franklin Gothic Demi, but the capital Q doesnt have a straight line like in this picture.

This image was a screenshot of one of my old thumbnails. My computer got formatted and I lost the font.

Comment: Hi user125986. We have some [requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and edit your question to include that information.

Comment: I have edited please un hold it

Comment: please read the requirements thoroughly. We ask that you provide us information from where your sample comes, and that you describe the typeface in at least your title. Sorry to be this blunt, but we have experienced severe backlash from font-identification questions by a huge amount of users, so these requirements are here to keep them manageable.

Comment: Done, now please un h0old it !

Comment: If you edit that image, and paint out the confusing background with white, leaving only the blue lettering, fontsquirrel matcherator will find a result for that font.

Comment: I have tried (removed outling background and made the text bright green) it makes the text into one huge piece instead of seperate letters.

Comment: You don't need to make the text bright green. Just paint out all the background.

Comment: I have edited it with the image I am talking about :0

Comment: Did you read what I said? Paint out the background with white so you are left with only the blue lettering.

Answer (score 0):

[Wendelin-Fett](https://fonts2u.com/wendelin-fett.font) from www.fonts2u.com

[image: WENDELIN]